# Extender controls may not be registered after PreRender. Controls added dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding controls to a form dynamically, then reading back the responses. To do this, I have to recreate the form on postback before trying to get at the responses.
At present, only fields that require a date have an AjaxControlToolkit MaskedEditExtender:

```
    case "DAT":
                            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                            tb.ID = "tbDat" + intQuestionCount.ToString();
                            tb.CssClass = "PositionCol3 SVSTextBox1";
                            tb.Width = 250;
                            // check for date range restricdtions and display in tooltip
                            strTooltip = "";
                            if (question.DateMaxDaysInPast != 0)
                            {
                                DateTime dtPastDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-Convert.ToInt32(question.DateMaxDaysInPast));
                                strTooltip = "Date must be after " + dtPastDate.ToShortDateString();
                            }
                            if (question.DateMaxDaysInFuture != 0)
                            {
                                DateTime dtFutureDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(question.DateMaxDaysInFuture));
                                if (strTooltip == "")
                                {
                                    strTooltip = "Date must be before " + dtFutureDate.ToShortDateString();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    strTooltip += " and before " + dtFutureDate.ToShortDateString();
                                }
                            }
                            tb.ToolTip = strTooltip; ;
                            // if this is a completed form look for saved response
                            if (intCompletedSurveyAnswerId != 0)
                            {
                                tb.Text = strAnswerText;
                            }
                            questionsPanel.Controls.Add(tb);

                            // add to list of controls
                            m_orderOfControls[intNumOfControls] = "TB";
                            intNumOfControls += 1;
                            // add to saved textboxes
                            m_dynamicTextBoxes[intTextBoxCount] = tb;
                            intTextBoxCount += 1;

                            // try add masked edit extender
                            AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditExtender maskedEdit = new AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditExtender();
                            maskedEdit.ID = "mk_" + tb.ID;
                            maskedEdit.TargetControlID = tb.ID;
                            maskedEdit.Mask = "99/99/9999";
                            maskedEdit.MaskType = AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditType.Date;
                            //maskedEdit.InputDirection = AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditInputDirection.RightToLeft;
                            questionsPanel.Controls.Add(maskedEdit);
                            // add to list of controls
                            m_orderOfControls[intNumOfControls] = "MK";
                            intNumOfControls += 1;
                            // add to saved textboxes
                            m_dynamicMasks [intMaskCount] = maskedEdit;
                            intMaskCount  += 1;


                            break;
```

m_orderOfControls, intNumOfControls, m_dynamicMasks, intMaskCount are all save as session vaiables, so that the form can be recreated on postback:

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        retrieveDynamicControlsFromSession();
        recreateForm();
    }
```

and:

```
    protected void recreateForm()
    {
        //
        // Form needs to be recreated after postback exactly as want sent out
        //
        try
        {

            int intNumOfLabels = 0;
            int intNumOfTextBoxes = 0;
            int intNumDdls = 0;
            int intNumCbls = 0;
            int intNumRbls = 0;
            int intNumCbs = 0;
            int intNumLitControls = 0;
            int intNumMaskedEditExtenders = 0;
            questionsPanel.Controls.Clear();

            foreach (string controlType in m_orderOfControls)
            {
                if (controlType != null)
                {
                    LiteralControl htmlControl = new LiteralControl();

                    switch (controlType)
                    {
                        case "MK":
                            AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditExtender maskedEdit = new AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditExtender();
                            maskedEdit = m_dynamicMasks[intNumMaskedEditExtenders];
                            intNumMaskedEditExtenders += 1;
                            questionsPanel.Controls.Add(maskedEdit);
                            break;
                        case "LB":
                            Label lbl = new Label();
                            lbl = m_dynamicLabels[intNumOfLabels];
                            intNumOfLabels += 1;
                            questionsPanel.Controls.Add(lbl);
                            break;
                        case "TB":
                            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
                            textBox = m_dynamicTextBoxes[intNumOfTextBoxes];
                            intNumOfTextBoxes += 1;
                            questionsPanel.Controls.Add(textBox);
                            break;
                        case "CB":
                            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
                            checkBox = m_dynamicCheckBoxes[intNumCbs];
                            intNumCbs += 1;
                            questionsPanel.Controls.Add(checkBox);
                            break;
                        case "CBL":
                            CheckBoxList checkBoxList = new CheckBoxList();
                            checkBoxList = m_dynamicCheckBoxLists[intNumCbls];
                            intNumCbls += 1;
                            questionsPanel.Controls.Add(checkBoxList);
                            break;
                        case "RBL":
                            RadioButtonList radioButtonList = new RadioButtonList();
                            radioButtonList = m_dynamicRadioButtonLists[intNumRbls];
                            intNumRbls += 1;
                            questionsPanel.Controls.Add(radioButtonList);
                            break;
                        case "HTML":
                            LiteralControl hmtlControl = new LiteralControl();
                            htmlControl = m_literalControls[intNumLitControls];
                            intNumLitControls += 1;
                            questionsPanel.Controls.Add(htmlControl);
                            break;
                        case "DDL":
                            DropDownList dropDownList = new DropDownList();
                            dropDownList = m_dynamicDropDownLists[intNumDdls];
                            intNumDdls += 1;
                            questionsPanel.Controls.Add(dropDownList);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    // end paragraph

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

On testing this, after form Save button has been used once or twice, I get this error: Extender controls may not be registered after PreRender.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try this inside OnInit
        if (this.DesignMode == true)
        {
            this.EnsureChildControls();
        }
        this.Page.RegisterRequiresControlState(this); ?

Comment: Would that go before or after the statements already in my OnInit?

Comment: I tried that - same error: protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);

            if (this.DesignMode == true) { this.EnsureChildControls(); } this.Page.RegisterRequiresControlState(this);

            retrieveDynamicControlsFromSession();
            recreateForm();
        }

Comment: do you override OnPreRender?

Comment: I believe so: protected override void OnPreRender

Comment: I found some links but I cannot test your code: http://jlchereau.blogspot.jp/2007/03/extender-controls-may-not-be-registered.html and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/dd00e997-c706-4817-9834-da266e87b16a/the-scriptmanager-must-appear-before-any-controls-that-need-it?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy or http://aspnetresources.com/blog/controls_may_not_be_registered_before_prerender . Hope one of this will fix your error.

Comment: No, all those links referred to 'before PreRender'. My error is 'after PreRender'.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have other ideas, maybe someone else got a fix for this.... this one is after PreREnder http://forums.asp.net/t/1061827.aspx